# How to get lowest value from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Problem 1**

How can I get lowest value from table (not null), for ID_CAR? For example, for ID_CAR 1 lowest value is 50, for ID_CAR 2 lowest value is 50 and for ID_CAR 3 lowest value is 300. I don't need duplicates, I need only one value for one car.

```
ID_CAR | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 | col_6 

1      | null  | 250   | 300   | null  | 900   | null
2      | 100   | null  | 300   | 600   | 200   | 100
1      | 300   | 100   | 800   | 100   | 50    | 900
3      | 300   | 4000  | null  | null  | null  | null
2      | null  | null  | null  | 50    | null  | 100
4      | 400   | 900   | 500   | 700   | 800   | 500
```

**Problem 2**
In this example, values in col_* are days. I need to add days to col_date and get lowest. For example lowest date for ID_CAR 1 is 2018-01-03 (col_2) and for ID_CAR 2 is 2018-01-15 (col_4).

```
ID_CAR | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 | col_6 | col_date

1      | null  | 2     | 3     | null  | 5     | null  | 2018-01-01
2      | 1     | null  | 3     | 6     | 10    | 10    | 2018-01-13
1      | 3     | 20    | 80    | 10    | 50    | 90    | 2018-01-02
3      | 30    | 40    | null  | null  | null  | null  | 2018-01-03
2      | null  | null  | null  | 5     | null  | 10    | 2018-01-10
4      | 10    | 9     | 5     | 70    | 8     | 50    | 2018-01-07
```

Comment: If I was going there, I wouldn't start from here :-(

Comment: this table needs normalization thats the real answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without `union` you can simply combine [least](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [min](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) function :

```
select
  ID_CAR,min(least(col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5,col_6)) lowest_value
from
  table
group by
  ID_CAR
```

or if you have `null`values you need `ifnull` or `coalesce` function

```
select
  ID_CAR,
  min(least(
    ifnull(col_1,~0),
    ifnull(col_2,~0),
    ifnull(col_3,~0),
    ifnull(col_4,~0),
    ifnull(col_5,~0),
    ifnull(col_6,~0)
  )) as lowest_value
from
  table
group by
  ID_CAR
```

- `~0` is the max bigint in mysql
- The opposite function of `least` is `greatest`
- The opposite function of `min` is `max` ;-)

*Works with Mysql, Oracle, Postgres, Hive ...*

**Problem 2**, something like this :

```
select
  ID_CAR,
  min(least(
    DATE_ADD(col_date, INTERVAL ifnull(col_1,0) DAY),
    DATE_ADD(col_date, INTERVAL ifnull(col_2,0) DAY),
    DATE_ADD(col_date, INTERVAL ifnull(col_3,0) DAY),
    DATE_ADD(col_date, INTERVAL ifnull(col_4,0) DAY),
    DATE_ADD(col_date, INTERVAL ifnull(col_5,0) DAY),
    DATE_ADD(col_date, INTERVAL ifnull(col_6,0) DAY)
  )) as lowest_date
from
  table
group by
  ID_CAR
```

or like this (except if all columns can be null):

```
select
  ID_CAR,
  DATE_ADD(col_date, INTERVAL min(least(
    ifnull(col_1,~0),
    ifnull(col_2,~0),
    ifnull(col_3,~0),
    ifnull(col_4,~0),
    ifnull(col_5,~0),
    ifnull(col_6,~0)
  )) DAY) as lowest_date
from
  table
group by
  ID_CAR
```

Comment: i like this better then @Utsav answer  `~0` looks like it the same value as a unsigned BIGINT value making it less error prone adjusting the values.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my first problem. But what about problem 2 when, I need add values to col_date and get lowest date?

Comment: @Jack, if it is ok for you, can you accept the answer. thank you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The following query will give you the required result

```
select tab.ID_CAR, min(tab.val) as lowest_value from
(
      (select ID_CAR,min(col_1) val
      from table
      group by ID_CAR)
  union
      (select ID_CAR,min(col_2) val
      from table
      group by ID_CAR)
  union
      (select ID_CAR,min(col_3) val
      from table
      group by ID_CAR)
  union
      (select ID_CAR,min(col_4) val
      from table
      group by ID_CAR)
  union
      (select ID_CAR,min(col_5) val
      from table
      group by ID_CAR)
  union
      (select ID_CAR,min(col_6) val
      from table
      group by ID_CAR)
) tab
group by tab.ID_CAR
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `UNION`  :

```
select id_car, min(val) as lowest_value
from (select id_car, col_1 as Val
      from table union 
      select id_car, col_2
      from table
      . . .
     ) t 
group by id_car;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this
If you are expecting values greater than 9999999999999999999, then use a higher values

```
select id_car,
min(least(coalesce(col_1,9999999999999999999),coalesce(col_2,9999999999999999999),coalesce(col_3,9999999999999999999),
          coalesce(col_4,9999999999999999999),coalesce(col_5,9999999999999999999),coalesce(col_6,9999999999999999999)
        )
    ) as min_val 
from your_table
group by id_car
```

Comment: Your SQLFiddle uses varchar instead of int for col_2, col_3 etc. which causes LEAST to not do integer comparisons.

Comment: I guess the `text to ddl` of SQLFiddle converted to varchar somehow. Anyways, the answer will still be the same. Removed the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach would be using least:

```
SELECT ID_CAR, least(t.col_1, t.col_2, t.col_3, t.col_4, t.col_5, t.col_6)
FROM
(SELECT ID_CAR, min(col_1) as col_1, min(col_2) as col_2, min(col_3) as col_3, min(col_4) as col_4, min(col_5) as col_5, min(col_6) as col_6
FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY ID_CAR) t;
```

**However**: If ANY argument to LEAST is NULL, it'll return NULL. You'll either need to convert the NULLs to a high value (which is a hack but will work in practice, see other answers for this).

Which means doing something like this:

```
SELECT ID_CAR, LEAST(col_1, col_2, col_3,
                     col_4, col_5, col_6) as l
FROM
(SELECT ID_CAR, 
   IFNULL(min(col_1), 9999)  as col_1, 
   IFNULL(min(col_2), 9999)  as col_2,
   IFNULL(min(col_3), 9999)  as col_3,
   IFNULL(min(col_4), 9999)  as col_4,
   IFNULL(min(col_5), 9999)  as col_5,
   IFNULL(min(col_6), 9999)  as col_6
FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY ID_CAR) t;
```

However, it might be good to use a trick to convert your table
into a three row table of the form:

```
car_id | attr | value
     1      1    NULL   ; or use strings such as "size"
     1      2     250
```